# Combine multiple FilesMatch rules in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to deny access for some IPs to my website completely.
Additionally I'd like to deny access for some other IPs to a certain file only.
The problem is, that the second rule seems to override the first one.

```
<FilesMatch "">
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 1.1.1.1
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^file\.exe$">
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 2.2.2.2
</FilesMatch>
```

In this stripped down example 1.1.1.1 will have access to file.exe although it was actually blocked by the first rule.

Expected result: 1.1.1.1 doesn't have access to anything (incl. file.exe), 2.2.2.2 has access to the website but not file.exe.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add `deny from 1.1.1.1` to the second one. As you say, the `allow from all` in the second block is overriding the first for `file.exe`. Also remove the empty filematch for the first, it's not doing anything.

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 1.1.1.1

<FilesMatch "^file\.exe$">
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 1.1.1.1
deny from 2.2.2.2
</FilesMatch>
```

Or for a simpler approach, you could try this:

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 1.1.1.1

<FilesMatch "^file\.exe$">
deny from 2.2.2.2
</FilesMatch>
```

Please let me know how you get on.

Comment: Well, I had this thought too, but 1.1.1.1 is just a short example. In reality, there's a living list of about 20 lines + comments. I definitely don't want to create a redundancy here that will need to be kept synchronous. Also your second example is likely missing your suggested line. Apart from that leaving out the FilesMatch scope, somehow seems to interfere with the rest of the htaccess file. Instead of 403 I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. But that's just a side node to point out that the empty FilesMatch somehow does make sense.

Comment: The redirection problem is due to `ErrorDocument 403 /`- I've removed that for testing purposes and will find another solution for this, if I can get your suggestion to work. The problem with your second suggestion is that it seems to implicitly override the allow statement, so file.exe can be accessed from 1.1.1.1 - You can replace that with 127.0.0.1 or ::1 to easily try that locally yourself, if you like.